# Leaflet doesn't want my layerGroup

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I've got a problem with leaflet layerGroups. First off, I'm getting some geoJSON-data to put some polygons on my map:

```
$http.get("common/geojson/berlin-districts.geojson")
        .success(function(data){
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map){
                $rootScope.districtData = L.geoJson(data.features,
                    {color: '#03f', fill:true, fillOpacity:0.05, opacity:0.15, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
                $rootScope.districtData.addTo(map);
....
```

This works, no problem. The onEachFeature enables me to select some of those Polygons:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.isSelected=false;
            //bind click
            layer.on('click', function (e) {
                if($rootScope.areaSelectionMode){
                    if(!layer.isSelected){
                        layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0.2, opacity:0.3});
                        layer.isSelected = true;
                        $scope.selectedAreas.push(layer);
...
```

The selected Polygons are stored in $scope.selectedAreas. 
Then, on another map, I want to display those chosen polygons! Should be easy, I thought:

```
leafletData.getMap('miniMap').then(function(map){
            map.removeControl(map.zoomControl);
            layers = L.layerGroup($scope.selectedAreas);
            layers.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layers.getBounds());
        })
```

This, however, doesn't work and I get this error:
**[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'bounds.min').**

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Someone at my work was having a similar issue. I think getBounds isn't available on the layer object. Could be wrong. I'm not sure how he fixed it. Sorry if that's not much use to you.

Comment: Here's something I did a while ago, converted a collection of layers to a feature group then called getBounds on that object. `var featureGroup = new L.featureGroup(layercollection); var bounds = featureGroup.getBounds(); map.fitBounds(bounds);`

Comment: oh, I should've specified: the problem is not the fitBounds-part. If I comment that out, I still get the same error.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?